# python array generation. How does this code work?

Tags: python

I need to translate some code to lua and I dont know what this part does exactly:

```
from math import prod
prob_generated = prod([w if b else (1-w) for (w,b) in zip(weights, bits)])
```

I know that I get the product of all values of the generated array but I dont know what exactly this syntax is. The only known variables in the code I use are `weights` (array) and `bits` (array).

Can somebody explain what is happening in this code example? (Or write this code in a better to read way)

Comment: its not a sum its a product

Comment: Ah yes, I will change that

Comment: @ApplePie I use `from math import prod`. I will edit my question

Answer (score 1):

Zip is a function that will create a list of tuples ("pairs") of elements from `weights` and `bits`. It does so by starting from the first element of both lists, pairs them, then moves on to the second, etc.

The `[expression for expression2 in enumerable]` construct is called a list comprehension. This generates a list on the fly. `expression2` here returns a single tuple of weight and bit within the list we've obtained from zip. `expression1` uses the ternary operator to return w if b is `truth-y` (non-zero, not `None`, not `[]` ...) otherwise we get `1-w`.

Finally, this list is passed to the `prod` function which appears to be a custom function. Can't help you with that one.

Comment: `prod` is the product function

Answer (score 1):

In complicated way But one line

```
weights = [1,2,3,4,5]
bits = [1,0,1,1,0]
prob_generated = ([w if b else (1-w) for (w,b) in zip(weights, bits)])
print(prob_generated)
```

In simple way but too many lines

```
weights = [1,2,3,4,5]
bits = [1,0,1,1,0]
prob_generated = []
for i in range(0,len(weights)):
    prob_generated.append((weights[i],bits[i]))
solution = []
for (i,j) in prob_generated:
    if(j):
        solution.append(i)
    else:
        solution.append(1-i)
prob_generated = solution
print(prob_generated)
```

Both give the same output which is this -

```
[1, -1, 3, 4, -4]
```

Comment: prob_generated is a number, not a list

Comment: I just sent the values inside the array. You can use the prod function on this array.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is functionally equivalent to

```
prob_generated = 1
for i in range(len(bits)):
    if bits[i]:
        prob_generated *= weights[i]
    else:
        prob_generated *= 1 - weights[i]
```